# Regex - Find a 8 letters word with either number/alphabets/both and ending with .php

Tags: php, regex, file

I am trying to find many 8 digited words using regex,

1. which should contain either number/alphabets/both
2. after that 8 digits it should end with .php
3. it should only have 8 digits neither 7 nor 6

I Tried this `\b\d{8}\b.php`

But I failed it only works for numbers for example

**12121212.php**

**23232323.php**

Also i don't need

**something-catergory.php**

**AB787C-category.php**

**has-bookshok.php**

The final result should be like ***abcd1234.php*** rather than ***something-abcd1234.php***

Comment: Is the input data a set of filenames or are you trying to extract the filenames from a long text?

Comment: Yes it is filename, not a long text

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use character class

`\b[a-zA-Z0-9]{8}\b`

- `\b` - Word boundry.
- `[a-zA-Z0-9]{8}` - match number, alphabets or both. ( {8} -> length must be 8 character)

***Update***

> The final result should be like abcd1234.php rather than
>   something-abcd1234.php

`\b[a-zA-Z0-9]{8}\.php$`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/x3Zby2/2/)

Well if you want complete string to match you need to use `^` anchor at start and `$` at end instead of `\b`

`^[a-zA-Z0-9]{8}\.php$`

Comment: it didn't work, it also finds file like **class-walker-category.php** i just need 8 digits file, there should be nothing before that.

Comment: @Nimesh well can you post possible input cases in question itself. what i did in above question is just edited your regex as per your question

Comment: I updated my question, I tried your edited answer. Sorry, still not working

Comment: @Nimesh check here everything is working https://regex101.com/r/x3Zby2/2/

Comment: @Nimesh updated. you can mark as correct one if it helped

Comment: **^[a-zA-Z0-9]{8}\.php$** should be the answer, Please update

Comment: @Nimesh well i added this answer and you told this is not what you want in your above comments.

Comment: But the link you sent it was working, previously you were missing ^.

Comment: Here is the link i sent as first edit https://regex101.com/r/x3Zby2/1 and it works fine. nothing is missing

Answer (score 1):

If your data is a list of filenames then this regex will work:

```
/^[a-z0-9]{8}\.php$/i
```

It asserts that the filename is exactly 8 `[a-zA-Z0-9]` characters followed by `.php`. Note that the `i` modifier makes it case insensitive so we don't have to specify `A-Z` in the character class as well.

Here's a [demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/Ei1Jb)

Comment: @CodeManiac The way I interpreted the question, I don't think it is supposed to match `something-abcd1234.php`. Unfortunately with no real sample input and expected output it's hard to be sure.

Comment: Sorry mate he's not sure what he want. i added same answer in one of my edit and he said he don't want this. and now saying he want this answer. removing my comments

Comment: @CodeManiac on the first attempt you were right but here in answer you missed ^. Nick has added extra / at beginning and /i at last, so it is not working as well. By the way i am trying it Cpanel File Manager.

Comment: @Nimesh those `/` are for PHP which you tagged your question for. If you had explained you were using Cpanel file manager at first I would have left them off.